# Unramified local Langlands

Tags: reference-request

Where can I find a complete proof of the unramified local Langlands correspondence for arbitrary reductive groups? Second sentence included because the automated system would not accept my question.

Comment: Isn't there only an unramified local Langlands correspondence for unramified reductive groups? (i.e. groups with a hyperspecial subgroup)?